# LINQ - Select Specific Columns

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is using Razor. In my Razor view, I am using a pre-written JavaScript library. That library expects some JSON in a form like:

```
var options = [
  { id=1, name='Joe', index=3 },
  { id=216, name='Bill', index=1 },
  { id=923, name='Katy', index=2 }
];
```

I am trying to populate/generate this array in my Razor view from a `List<MyEntity>`. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
var options= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Options.Select(c => new { id=c.Id, name=c.FullName, index=c.Position } )))');
```

When this runs, I get an array of object. However, each object has EVERY property generated as a field. Is there a way for me to select specific fields so that I can trim down the size of what's generated. These objects have hundreds of properties. So, it becomes really expensive from a bandwidth perspective to send them across the wire.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to not overcomplicate it by doing something like:

```
<script>
    var options = [];

    @{
        foreach(var option in @Model.Options)
        {      
            <text>
                var obj = {
                            id:'@(option.Id)', 
                            name: '@(option.Name)', 
                            index: '@(option.Position)'
                          };

                options.push(obj);
            </text> 
        }
    }    

    ... 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code in the past and its worked.  It requires the Json.NET library: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
var options = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Options.Select(c => new { id=c.Id, name=c.FullName, index=c.Position } )));
```